# Firebase custom token vs service account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

We have android app with local users list. The app has single dedicated user in Firebase (other users are managed locally), which should be used to access Realtime Database. UID would be used to apply security Rules and restrict access to specific data elements. I think we have two options: custom token or service account (with databaseAuthVariableOverride).

I wonder what security issues we might get by using service account approach? Does it get full access? Maybe we could restrict that to minimal set of actions?

Custom token approach might have problem with token expiration. Is there a way to significantly extend token validity? What could be the best way to generate custom token on android?

Answer (score 0):

With the service account, you are hard coding access to your database to all installed applications, in other words, everyone that installs your app, will see the exact same thing.

You would normally use the token approach so you tailor access to different nodes on the database to different users. This is normally achieved by setting a few simple rules for your nodes, for example :

```
    // Sample firebase rules
    {
      "rules": {
        "messages": {
          // Only admin servers with service accounts should r/w here
          ".read": "auth.uid == 'server-with-svc-acct'",
          ".write": "auth.uid == 'server-with-svc-acct'",
          "$user_id": {
             // Users can only read their own nodes
             ".read": "auth.uid == $user_id",
             ".write": "auth.uid ==  $user_id",

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

You can check the details on how to auth with Google+ in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), but in general terms once you auth, you can get a unique user ID and so write to the desired node on your real time database. The user won't have access to any other node, as the rules will restrict him :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
        // ...
    }
};
// ...
```

For your server, where it is safe to keep your service account secrets, you can initiate a Firebase connection in the following way (notice the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` ?, it matches the `auth.uid` we used on the root of the `messages` node).

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "path/to/project-name-secrets.json",
  databaseURL: "https://project-name.firebaseio.com",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "server-with-svc-acct"
  }
});
```

More information about this can be found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start) as well.